# Opening Embedded Excel Workbook on Sharepoint using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, sharepoint

I am currently attempting to open an embedded excel file found on my company's sharepoint:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<head>
<title>
Project
</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Open("sharepoint_url/myfile.xlsx");


</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

However, whenever I run this, I keep receiving the following error:

**Subscript out of range**

I was hoping someone could shed some light as to how I should approach this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="form1">
  <input type=button onClick="openmyfile()" value="Open File">
  <br><br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function openmyfile() {
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("sharepoint_url/myfile.xlsx");
  }
</script>
```